# Can a Dao cast spells while Earth Gliding?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

A [dao](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dao) (MM, p. 143) is described as having the following ability:

> ***Earth Glide.*** The dao can burrow through nonmagical, unworked earth and stone. While doing so, the dao doesn't disturb the material it moves through.

Dao’s are also described as having innate spellcasting.

**Can a Dao cast spells from within the earth (i.e. such as if encountering other burrowing beasts)? Also, can a Dao cast spells from within the earth out into an open chamber?**

Answer (score 3):

#### He can, but not every spell

Since dao only has darkvision, it doesn't actually see through the material it's gliding through, so it doesn't see much and it doesn't have a "clear path" to many points in space.

So it is pretty much limited to spells with range of **touch** or **self**. Fortunately for the dao, about half of its spells are like that.

Comment: note that spells such as [*Conjure Elemental*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-elemental) would also work, since it doesn't require you to see the point (of origin of the cube) within range.

Comment: @PixelMaster Can you support this point with anything? Is this sage advice, or something? I would read it in the way that you are targeting that area, so you would need a clear path to it. In other words, it's hard to choose an area when you can't see it. (But that just may be my opinion.)

Comment: Yeah, not every spell needs line of sight, but they do require [a clear path to the target](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#AClearPathtotheTarget) (i.e. "line of effect"): "To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover. If you place an area of effect at a point that you can't see and an obstruction, such as a wall, is between you and that point, the point of origin comes into being on the near side of that obstruction."

Comment: my bad, I misinterpreted that.

Comment: although the Earth Elemental can move through the earth as well. Could you conjure him already *in* the ground?

Comment: @PixelMaster Reading the spell again I would not be against it as a DM, since they even use the example of the elemental rising from earth, it seems close to just letting him form **in** the ground. But I don't think the spell really allows it RAW.

Comment: @J.E Lol we're both blind :D the spell states “Choose an area of air, earth, fire, or water that fills a 10-foot cube within range“. Not only *can* you summon him underground, you actually *have to* ^^

Comment: @PixelMaster read that a bit further, you just need a bunch of rocks to act as a "portal" of sorts, from which the elemental emerges; it doesn't necessarily mean that you summon in in the middle of it. Notice how the elemental then appears *within 10 feet* of that cube, not *within the cube*.