# Can a character dodge/fly if they use up all their speed?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, forced-movement, dodge

There's something about the language in the rules for Dodging and Flying that confuses me. In both cases, both can only performed so long as the character's Speed is not 'reduced to 0'.

By that logic, if a character with 30 feet speed, were to say use the full 30 feet speed on their turn, would that prevent them from taking the Dodge action?

Likewise, if a creature had, say, a Flying speed of 60 feet, would there character have to fly 55 ft in order to stay aloft or risk falling?

(As a side note, how do attacks like Thunderwave which force movement play into this? If a Thunderwave hits a 30 feet speed character who has only moved 25 feet, would that prevent the character from being able to use Dodge until their next turn?)

Comment: Are you the same as [this Gan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171638/52137)? If so, you might want to complete registration (so you get login credentials) and go through the process of getting your accounts [merged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you own all your questions (and the associated rep and privileges).

Answer (score 29):

## Movement does not reduce your speed.

The way Speed works in D&D 5e is as follows:

- Every character and monster has a *speed*, which is the distance in feet that the character or monster can walk in 1 round.
- Some creatures and characters additionally have a *flying speed*, which is how far they can fly in 1 round.
- After moving its speed on a turn, a creature still has that speed. Movement doesn't reduce your speed. It just expends your allowed movement for that round, which is a number of feet equal to your speed.

There are many ways in the game for your speed to become 0, but movement is not one of them. For example:

- Being *grappled* or *restrained* reduces your speed to 0.
- Being *exhausted* can reduce your speed to 0.

See the sections on "Speed" and "Conditions" in the Basic Rules.

### Being moved by force does not count against your allowed movement.

If your character gets forcibly moved by an effect like Thunderwave, this does not count against your allowed movement for the round.

Answer (score 9):

### Movement isn’t Speed

Using your movement for a turn doesn't affect your actual speed.  Even if you've moved 30, 60 (via the Dash action), or even 90 (double-Dash with something like the Rogue's Cunning Action) feet, your speed is still 30.

Your speed being reduced to zero is a result of things like being tied up or paralyzed, not just walking.  Neither willing nor forced movement causes you to lose the ability to Dodge or fly (unless it says otherwise, of course).